# Hot to put one layout below another one in CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

In my Android app I want to put one layout below another one in CoordinatorLayout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/layout1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#F00"
         android:orientation="vertical">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Layout 1" />

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="..." />

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="..." />

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/layout2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#F0F"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         app:layout_anchor="@id/layout1"
         app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Layout 2" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

I expect to see `layout2` below `layout1` I see it inside.

[image]

How could I achieve to put it below?

Comment: Why would you do that? Will you need `CoordinatorLayout` for anchoring fabs or etc? Because it seems like it might not work as expected.

Comment: I'm trying to create the animation: when I click the button red layout goes up and purple one should do the same. If I use `LinearLayout` purple one stays at his place even when red oe goes up

Comment: @Vitalii Show us what kind of animation do you want?

Comment: If you refer to my picture, purple layout should be below the red one. When I click to a button in the red one, I want to make it go up (and disappear after) All items on the layout have to go up too.